# Show that $\sin(z)$ is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I have show that the function $\sin(z)$ satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations but don't know where to go from here.

If it saves some working for you they are

$$du/dx=-\sin(x)\cosh(y)$$          $$dv/dy=-\sin(x)\cosh(y)$$

$$du/dy=\cos(x)\sinh(y)$$            $$dv/dx=-\cos(x)\sinh(y)$$

Comment: Do you know what "analytic" means?

Comment: Alternatively, $\sin(z) = -\frac{i}{2}(e^{iz} - e^{-iz})$ is obtained from analytic functions by addition, composition, and multiplication, hence is analytic.

Comment: Since the partial derivatives are continuous, the function is also real-differentiable. Thus, it's analytic.

Comment: I don't understand: if you wanted to prove $\,\sin z\,$ is analytic then you already did the hard work with those partial derivatives! What else do you want? Do you know what "analytic" means?

Comment: I haven't been given a definition anywhere but I do have the theorem that "if the partial derivates of f exist and are continous on $omega$ and the Cauchy Riemann differential equations are satisfied there, then f is analytic on $omega$"

Comment: Do I just need to state that sin(z) is a continous function?

Comment: @ChrisEagle sorry forgot to tag you in my comment

Answer (score 13):

By definition we have

$$\sin(z) = \frac{1}{2\imath} \cdot \left(e^{\imath \, z}-e^{-\imath \, z}\right) $$

Since the sum of two analytic functions is analytic, it suffices to show that $z \mapsto e^{\imath \, z}$ and $z \mapsto e^{-\imath \, z}$ are analytic. Let $z:=x+ \imath \, y$ ($x,y \in \mathbb{R}$), then

$$e^{\imath \, z} = e^{\imath \, x} \cdot e^{-y} = \underbrace{e^{-y} \cdot \cos(x)}_{=:u(x,y)}+\imath \, \underbrace{e^{-y} \cdot \sin x}_{=:v(x,y)}$$

From 
$$\partial_x u(x,y) = - e^{-y} \cdot \cos(x) = \partial_y v(x,y) \\
\partial_y u(x,y) = - e^{-y} \cdot \cos(x) = - \partial_x v(x,y)$$

we see that the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied. Since the partial derivatives exist (and are continuous) we conclude that $z \mapsto e^{\imath \, z}$ is analytic. A similar argumentation shows that $z \mapsto e^{-\imath \, z}$ is analytic.

Comment: How could we leave out $\frac{1}{2i}$ and simply show $e^{iz}$ and $e^{-iz}$ are analytic?

Comment: @TheLastCipher If $z \mapsto f(z)$ is an analytic function, then $z \mapsto c f(z)$ is analytic for any constant $c \in \mathbb{C}$. Since $z \mapsto e^{iz}+e^{-iz}$ is analytic (as sum of two analytic functions) we get that $z \mapsto 1/(2i) (e^{iz}+e^{-iz})$ is analytic.

Answer (score 8):

To show $\sin z$ is analytic.

\begin{align}
\sin z&= \sin (x+iy)\\
&= \sin x \cos iy + \cos x\sin iy\\ 
&=\sin x\cosh y + i\cos x \sinh y\\
u&= \sin x \cosh y\\ v&= \cos x \sinh y \\
\frac {∂u}{\partial x} &= \cos x \cosh y\\
\frac {∂u}{∂y}&= \sin x\sinh y\\
\frac {∂v}{∂x}&= -\sin  x \sinh y \\
\frac {∂v}{∂y}&= \cos x \cosh y\\
\frac d{dx} \cosh x &= \sinh x\\
\frac {∂u}{\partial x} &= \frac {∂v} {∂y}\\
 \frac {∂v}{∂x} &= -\frac {∂u}{∂y}\\
\end{align}
Hence the cauchy-riemann equations are satisfied.

Thus $\sin z$ is analytic.

Answer (score 0):

$\sin$ and $\cos$ can be defined by the following differential equations

- $\cos(0) = 1$
- $\sin(0) = 0$
- $\cos' = -\sin$
- $\sin' = \cos$

It can be shown that there's exactly one way to define $\sin$ and $\cos$ such that they satisfy those differential equations.

Let $f(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^ix^{2i}}{(2i)!}$ and $g(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^ix^{2i + 1}}{(2i + 1)!}$. Both of those series converge on all of $\mathbb{R}$ and it's not that hard to show that every power series that converges on all of $\mathbb{R}$ is analytic on all of $\mathbb{R}$. So $f$ and $g$ are analytic on all of $\mathbb{R}$. It can also be shown that

- $f(0) = 1$
- $g(0) = 0$
- $f' = -g$
- $g' = f$

Therefore $f = \cos$ and $g = \sin$ and so $\sin$ and $\cos$ are analytic on all of $\mathbb{R}$.